# Can't empty trash

Tags: trash, gvfs

I visited a lot of forums but found no answer. I have 5 files in my trash bin and I can't delete them, at first after I clicked on the empty trash button it would freeze, now when I do that it just says "preparing" and displays an error while trying to delete files.

I tried deleting it via BleachBit but nothing, tried with terminal command `sudo rm -Rf ~/.Trash/*` it doesn't work either. I found out that one of my folders is immutable, I tried to disable that via terminal it didn't work, I can't even restore it, it freezes again.

I've been using Ubuntu 13.10 for few weeks and I am new to Linux. How can I solve this?

Comment: Isn't trash in `~/.local/share/Trash` instead of `~./Trash`? (`~` represents the home directory by the way). So `rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash` may work, but try not to remove anything important. If you are VERY sure you could run it as root, but then you would need to run `sudo rm -rf /home/USERNAME/.local/share/Trash` instead. Be careful with the -f option.

Comment: @Lucio A new Q should get closed by Old Q as duplicate.

Comment: @raaz that is a stupid rule

Comment: @raaz there's no rule that states so. The question with better quality answers should be the master.

Comment: @Braiam Look at the answers, they are same. you dont even look. bravo

Answer (score 75):

Open your terminal and type the following command to clear the trash

```
 sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

Comment: It worked thank you! why is not the official answer? sloopy OP-ers ...

Comment: On 16.04 this was `sudo rm -rf .local/share/Trash/files/*`

Comment: mark this as answer , i command you! haha

Comment: thanks!this saves the day.

Comment: this didn't work for me, trash is still 99% of drive

Comment: @Garglesoap if this doesn't work, perhaps trash is stored elsewhere; try https://askubuntu.com/a/468745/17060 (which imho is to be preferred, in any case)